# Install ubuntu with windows-7

Tags: installation, windows-7, 64-bit

How to install ubuntu without removing my pre-installed Windows-7,

My system is 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Ubuntu live-dvd, live-cd (for version 12.04) or live-usb, then launch it. During installation, click "Install next to Windows 7". Ubuntu will be installed without removing Windows.

Depending on the chosen version, you may have to choose to change Windows 7's partition size (resizing the partition doesn't delete any data).

Comment: Selecting this option will automatically select appropriate partition sizes, OP will not have to provide it with a partition size.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 Depends on Ubuntu version... 13.04 : you're right but 12.04 he'd have to choose. Am editing answer.